# Need to Intergrate Airpush ads for basic4android

Tags: android, basic4android

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/additional-libraries-classes-official-updates/11832-airpush-library.html

I followed these instructions but It wont let me to compile app. I'm Using version 1.9. It looks like code changed but there help forum not updated correct code.